# Manual input date in Kendo Grid DatePicker not working

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm facing a problem that I can't understand. I'm using Kendo Grid with InCell edit and I have a DateTime field in my Model.

When the grid enters in edit mode, the calendar is shown, but the grid only saves the inputed value if I select the value from the calendar. If I input the field manually, the value is not saved and the cell is not marked has dirty.

If it helps, I'm using MVC with Razor sintax.

Tks in advance!

Comment: Is pressing enter helping when you enter the value manually?

Comment: @Pechka - Thank's for your answer. I found a simple workaround and I updated my own question so others can use it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround in Kendo's forums:

> *By design, the DatePicker does not raise the change event when the value is set programmatically - it raises only if the date is modified by the end-user. In case you need to trigger the change event, you can use jQuery trigger().*
>
> *For example:*
>
> `var datePicker = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker");`
>
> `datePicker.value("01/01/2001");`
>
> `datePicker.trigger("change");`

Reference:
http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/date-time-pickers/datepicker-change-event.aspx

So basically what I did was to force the change event manually.

Comment: how to get the manually entered date.with this var datePicker = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").value(); its not giving the value, it works only with the calendar selection